# Using jQuery in place of document.getElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I would like to use

```
$("#fooid")
```

in place of

```
document.getElementById("fooid")
```

because I'm getting the id *with* the `#` in front of it. While you can remove it easily enough, there is a fair amount of intermixing between when I'm using a jQuery selector and when I'm using native DOM calls. In particular this is being called inside a chart draw, which seems to expect a native DOM object back. Giving it this extended jQuery object makes it choke and turn purple.

Is there a way I can get jQuery to "play nice" and pretend to give, or return instead, a native object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to get the DOM object:

```
$("#fooid").get(0);
```

Or a bit shorter version:

```
$("#fooid")[0];
```

Comment: +1, additionally, `.get()` with no arguments returns an array of DOM nodes.

Answer (score 1):

With [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)